# dynamic nesting of ruby blocks

Tags: ruby

Imagine i have some resource objects with a run method, which executes the block parameter under the lock held for that resource.  For example, like this:

```
r = Resource("/tmp/foo")
r.run { ... }
```

How can I write a ruby method which takes an array of resources and executes its block parameter under the lock held for all resources, like:

```
def using_resources(*res, &block)
  r[0].run do; r[1].run do; r[2].run do ...   

    yield;

  end; end; end; ...
end
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 10):

You could also do this using `#inject`:

```
def using_resources(*resources, &block)
  (resources.inject(block){ |inner,resource| proc { resource.run(&inner) } })[]
end
```

As you step through the array, you wrap each resource's invocation of the previous Proc in a new Proc, and then pass that to the next resource.  This gets the locks in reverse order (the last resource given is the first one unlocked), but that could changed by using `resources.reverse.inject ...`

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that this is best done using recursion

Here is the code:

```
def using_resources(*res, &block)

   first_resource = res.shift

   if res.length > 0 
     first_resource.run do
      using_resources(*res, &block)
     end
   else
     first_resource.run do
       block.call
     end
   end

end
```

And use it like so:

```
using_resources Resource.new('/tmp'), Resource.new('http://stackoverflow.com') do
  do_some_processing
end
```

You do say, "which takes an array of resources." If you have an `Array` already and need to use it, you can either splat the `Array` outside the call:

```
 using_resources *my_array do
   do_some_processing
 end
```

Or inside the method definition, which allows you to call it either with an `Array` or a list of `Resource`s:

```
def using_resources(*res, &block)
  res = [*res]
  # rest as above
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post an extension to @rampion's solution for the case where `run()` yields a value that you would like to use in the innermost block, like this:

```
def using_resources(*res, &block)
  r[0].run do |v0|; r[1].run do |v1|; r[2].run do |v2| ...

    yield [v0, v1, v2];

  end; end; end; ...
end
```

For example, this would arise if `run` was like `File.open`, where it yields a resource (eg, a file object) that you can use in your given block, but which is torn down after your block completes.

Here is the function:

```
def nested_do( args, func, &block )
  args.reverse.inject(block) do |inner, a|
      Proc.new do |acc|
          func.call(a) do |v|
              acc.append(v)
              inner.call(acc)
          end
      end
  end
  .call([])
end
```

To nest calls to `run` and collect up their yielded values, you would do:

```
res = [ Resource('a'), Resource('b'), Resource('c') ]
func = Proc.new {|r,&b| r.run(&b)}
nested_do( res, func ) do |vals|
    puts("Computing with yielded vals: #{vals}")
end
```

### Example

Here is a function like `File.open`, except it opens a "secret" resource,
which the caller can never use in the caller's scope, because
it is torn down after the yield() returns:

```
def open_secret(k)
    v = "/tmp/secret/#{k}"
    puts("Setup for key #{k}")
    yield v
    puts("Teardown for key #{k}")
end
```

Here is how to dynamically nest calls to `open_secret`:

```
nested_do([:k1,:k2,:k3], Proc.new {|k,&b| open_secret(k,&b)} ) do |rs|
    puts("Computing with 'secret' resources SIMULTANEOUSLY: #{rs}")
end
```

Prints:

```
Setup for key k1
Setup for key k2
Setup for key k3
Computing with 'secret' resources SIMULTANEOUSLY: ["/tmp/secret/k1", "/tmp/secret/k2", "/tmp/secret/k3"]
Teardown for key k3
Teardown for key k2
Teardown for key k1
```

### Update

In hindsight, using `inject` required a lot of brain-bending. Here is a superior implementation that uses recursion:

```
def nested_do(args, func, acc=[], &block)
    return block.call(acc) if args.size == 0

    a = args.pop
    func.call(a) do |v|
        acc.append(v)
        nested_do( args, func, acc, &block)
    end
end
```